# Disable stash on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have decided that the working teams shall not use statsh/unstash but instead rely on package managers to retrieve their dependencies.

Is there're any way to enforce that ? The best would be to simply disable the step at Jenkins level

Comment: I may be missing a different meaning of terminology here, but I can't imagine what the relationship would be between stash/unstash (which I'm guessing you mean the git commands or similar?), package managers (like Composer/Nuget/NPM?) and Jenkins (running test builds? deploying to test environments?)

Comment: Jenkins has a step stash/unstash command https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build i would like to disable it to force dev to use our package manager (connan) to retrieve packages instead of stash/unstashing files from repositories using the jenkins command (bad practice)

Comment: OK, I still can't quite picture the scenario. Is it that your developers have access to write their own Jenkins pipelines, but you don't trust them to follow best practices?

Comment: this is exactly that. moreoever, we have identified memory leaks with stash/unstash so we want to make sure it'S not used